# What does $\frac{dx}{dt}$ mean?

Tags: calculus

If $x = 3t-2$, with $x$ in units of meters and $t$ in units of seconds then the velocity is

$$V = \frac{dx}{dt} = 3\,\text{m}/\text{s}$$

How is the answer $3$ m/s? What does $\frac{dx}{dt}$ mean?

Comment: It stands for the **derivative** of $x$ with respect to $t$. It's a very widely used concept in mathematics, but I suggest against learning about it through physics. Grab a math textbook instead.

Comment: I've been trying that. I still don't understand.

Comment: If you don't know about derivatives then it does not make much sense to ask this question. You need to go back and learn what derivatives are and how to take derivatives of simple functions like $3t-2$.

Comment: Well, it took me several months to learn derivatives when I first heard of them, so don't panic.

Comment: Isn't 3t-2 just 1?

Comment: @user366783 You have a long way to go if you think $3\cdot t - 2$ is equal to $1$... And I don't mean to be insulting. I want to say you need to slow down - you can't learn to run unless you first learn how to walk.

Comment: It should be 1. Look, (1) 3 t 1-0 - 2. That's 1.

Comment: "$3t-2$" is a function, specifically a line.  It has slope $3$ and $y$-intercept $2$.  It is not constant.  (To be constant, it must have slope $0$.)  So this line is not constantly $1$.

Comment: SO how would I manipulate the #s to get 3 m/s?

Comment: Are you familiar with limits?  Could you, for instance, compute $\lim_{t \rightarrow 2} 3t - 2$?

Comment: I took calculus last semester, but I don't remember it at all. Was it 3(t) -2 = 4?

Comment: Assuming that's an innocent typo, do you recall/have available the definition of the derivative?

Comment: A bar of expensive chocolate says user366783 is trolling.

Comment: You wouldn't believe how often I get accused of being a troll. Why do you think that's the case?

Comment: @user366783, you sure you are not trolling?

Comment: Why do you think I'm trolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed is the space that you travel per unit of time, which can be computed as your position at time $t+1$ minus your position at time $t$.

$$x(t+1)-x(t)=(3(t+1)-2)-(3t-2)=3.$$

More generally, taking any two instants $t_0,t_1$, we get the average speed during this lapse,

$$\frac{x(t_1)-x(t_0)}{t_1-t_0}=\frac{(3t_1-2)-(3t_0-2)}{t_1-t_0}=3.$$

This is also written

$$\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=3.$$

We could very well stop here, but things get more interesting when the position is no more a linear function of time like $Vt+x_0$, and the speed changes over time. In such a case, we compute the average speed in a time lapse that is as small as possible, i.e. that shrinks to zero. Then we denote

$$\lim_{\Delta t\to0}\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\frac{dx}{dt},$$ wich is the derivative of the position on time. This is called the instantaneous speed.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is the way in $m$ and $t$ is the time in $s$ .

$d$ means infinitesimal small differenz

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(3t-2)=\lim\limits_{h\to\pm 0}(\frac{[3(t+h)-2]-[3t-2]}{[t+h]-[t]})\frac{m}{s}=\frac{3h}{h}|_{h\to 0}\frac{m}{s}=3\frac{m}{s}$

Answer (score 1):

If $x= 3t -2$ describes a coordinate, $x$, in function of time $t$, then $\frac{dx}{dt}$ represents the rate of change of the coordinate, $x$, in time $t$, i.e. *velocity*.
 $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is sometimes called instantaneous rate (as opposed of average rate of change $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$) of change of $x$ with respect of $t$.

If the same equation represents a line on the 2D plane, then the ratio $\frac{dx}{dt}$ represents the slope of line tangent to the line represented by the original equation.

---

<sub>To understand the result better check [the rules for differentiation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules)</sub>